# Codeigniter _remap function is setting its own default value to the string "index"

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm writing the back-end for a website using CodeIgniter. I want to be able to use these two URLs: 
(1) website.com/product (to return data on all products) 
(2) website.com/product/2 (to return data on product with e.g. ID 2).

I have a Product controller, here is the relevant code in outline:

```
class Product extends CI_Controller

public function _remap($id = -1)
{
    $this->my_function($id)
}

public function my_function($n)
{
    if ($n == -1) 
    {   
        // Code to return data on all products
    }
    else
    {
        // Code to return specific product data
    }
}
```

I'm using `_remap()` because without it, when the URL is of the form website.com/product/id, codeigniter will want to interpret the id as a method. If the URL is just website.com/product then the $id variable is set to have a default value of -1. But bizarrely this doesn't happen: instead $id is set to the string "index" (I checked this by adding `var_dump($id);` to the _remap() function).

What is going on?

Comment: I could just change the if clause to `if($n=="index")` but I want to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove the _remap function.

```
class Product extends CI_Controller {

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index($id = -1)
{
    if($id == -1)
    {
        echo 'full list';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'work on id' . $id;
    }
}

}
```

Then create a route in `config/routes.php`

```
$route['product/(:num)'] = 'product/index/$1';
```

---

If you really want to use _remap then you'll need to do something like the following:

```
public function _remap($method, $params = array())
{
    if($method == 'index'){
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, 'my_function'), $params);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm reluctant to do this because what I presented in my original question is actually a simplification. The URLs are actually of the form website.com/television/2 or website.com/computer etc. with Television, Computer etc. being controllers which extend Product. So I'd have to add new routing rules for all of these controllers (there are other controllers which don't extend Product so I couldn't just do `$route['(:any)/(:num)']`). I could do it, but I'd really like to understand what's going on with the bizarre behaviour of remap().

Comment: `_remap()` first argument is always going to be the method that the controller is going to call.  In your case it's index because thats the default method that CI can call.  Functions can't begin with a number.  I'll update my _remap method so you can see how to use it with parameters.

Comment: I think I understand: `_remap()` is designed to take methods as arguments, hence it insists that its default argument should be "index", since this is the default for a codeigniter controller.

Comment: This enforcing of a particular default argument is not typical of PHP functions, I think.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Index is the default method if there is no method defined in the URL parameters, and it's functionality is a feature of CodeIgniter.  Your code in this example would also work with `website.com/product/my_function/1`